# Unbind click after POST with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, sorting, unbind

I'm trying to create a sort with `jquery`. It works just the first time that the user click on `th` tag but after the POST request on  the ajax function the user can't click on the `th` tag again. This is my code.
Help please, thanks in advance.

```
$("#sortHeader th").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    sortValue= $(this).attr("data-value");
    $(this).siblings('data-sort').attr('class', 'sorting');
    if($(this).hasClass('sorting')){
        $(this).attr('class', 'sorting_asc');
        sortOrder="asc";
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('sorting_asc')){
        $(this).attr('class','sorting_desc');
        sortOrder="desc";    
    }
    else  if($(this).hasClass('sorting_desc')){
        $(this).attr('class', 'sorting_asc');
        sortOrder="asc";
    }
    var saved =  $('#sortHeader').clone();//save state sort active column
    sort(this, saved);// function to call data on Controller
}); 

function sort(e,saved) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Method","Controller")',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: { query: null, search: $('#QueryString').val(), sort: sortOrder, sort_value: sortValue, Id: $('#Id').val() },
        success: function (data) {
            $("body").html(data);
           //replace the headers with the old state
            $('#sortHeader').replaceWith(saved);
            $("#sortHeader th").unbind("click")// unbind click event
        },
    })
};
```

Comment: try  `$("#sortHeader th").unbind()`

Comment: I'm confused.. is the problem that you can't sort after the post or that you can sort?

Comment: the problem is  that I can't sort after the POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line `$("#sortHeader th").unbind("click")` from your `ajax` `success` function and you need `click` event delegation as your contents are dynamically loading like following.

```
$(document).on('click', '#sortHeader th', function () {
    // do your task here
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Azim for your corrections, I'm  new here and actually my main language is Spanish, so I'm really bad with English grammar. I'll try to improve it.